# Java : Sort Collection<Class> given a custom order

Tags: java, sorting

I would like to sort a `List/Set` of `Class` given a personnal order (like `A.class` < `B.class` < `C.class` for instance). But `Class` doesn't implements `Comparable`, and I obviously can't customize the class `Class` without rewriting the whole Java language, so what are my options?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom Comparator. Just implement that interface and you can use it with Collections.sort() and sorted sets (pass the comparator as constructor)

```
Comparator<Class<?>> c=new Comparator<Class<?>>{
  @Override
  int compare(Class<?> a, Class<?> b) { 
     // your comparison logic 
  }
};

List<Class<?>> list= ...
Collections.sort(list, c);

Set<Class<?>> set=new TreeSet<>(c);
```

Comment: Ok. Got it! I knew only about the other way of sorting.
Thanks a lot. I try that right now

Comment: Damn, marked as dupe before answering. But try comparing by the class' simple name.

Comment: Actually I need to compare with instanceof. Otherwise, I wouldn't bother carrying a List<Class>. I would just use a List<String>. But thanks.